# Change starting date for a second time after accepting offer

Tags: consulting

I already looked at other posts which is why I'm posting this because I feel my case is a bit unique and needs explanation.

I originally selected my start day preference to be as late as possible because of I would be out of town for family situations. I was persuaded by a friend that that was the stupidest idea since that's sacrificing a month of salary. So, I emailed the recruiter saying I can actually start earlier. Later, I realized that I still need to be out of town due to the same family situation, I contacted the recruiters but they said that the later slots (for start date/training/new hire orientation) are already taken. They said if a slot empties up or if someone want to switch then they will contact me. However, they have not contacted me and I think I will be starting at the earlier starting date. **Can I still contact them to ask whether I can delay my starting date? If yes, how should I phrase the question?** Thank you!

**Since the recruiter said the next fiscal year is very soon, can I ask to start next fiscal year?** 2 of my friends (for another company) was able to do this, and one of them was even able to push it to 1 year later since he had to be abroad for some issues

Comment: There are plenty records of this question amongst the Workplace Stack Exchange, have a search you'll find your answer :)

Comment: Not a duplicate IMO as the complicating factor of this being a second u-turn on start date significantly alters the situation from the linked questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here isn't so much that you are asking to start later - more that you have already agreed a start date, moved it up, then want to move it back  again.

Even worse for you is that you've already had an indication via the recruiter that this is unlikely to be possible due to the on-boarding slots being filled so your request wouldn't just be messing the company around but potentially other people as well.

For sure you can contact them and ask if you can still rearrange but you have to be prepared for them not only to say no but also for this to give them the perception that you are erratic and unreliable. And I'm not sure that they would be wrong to think so.

Life happens(TM) and reasonable people understand that sometimes events outside of your control mean that plans have to be rearranged - in this case though it actually *is* something under your control and you've dug yourself a bit of a hole.

Realistically all you can do here is either take it on the chin or you can take the gamble of making a negative first impression.

Personally I wouldn't be pressing the issue unless there really wasn't any way of making the earlier start date work.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply! since the recruiter also mentioned about fiscal year, is it common for people to change offer to next fiscal year? i have heard a case where the person pushed it back to next year. And then another case where the person originally agreed on a starting date but few weeks before the starting date, pushed it back to next fiscal year

Comment: also thank you so much for clarifying my case that this is not a duplicate @motosubatsu

Comment: @CocoLi Not sure on the fiscal-year aspect to be honest - some companies would prefer it some not, it would depend upon lots of factors that we can't possibly know